# Can someone explain me with this pandas code?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I just wanna know what is the meaning of this code.

```
one_value_cols = [col for col in train.columns if train[col].nunique() <= 1]

one_value_cols_test = [col for col in test.columns if test[col].nunique() <= 1]

one_value_cols == one_value_cols_test
```

Comment: It's filtering for columns that have all the same values. Usually these are uninformative features and so can be discarded. In this case it is checking if the same columns meet this criteria in the training and test sets.

Comment: Can you explain it via the python term, I mean what is "col for col" ?

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python it's a list comprehension, it's pretty basic python. I would suggest doing a few beginners python tutorials if you haven't seen this before. Worry about pandas later.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you see here is called *list comprehension*, a useful way to fill one list with elements of another list that meet some condition: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: The result of this code, give False. Just tell me what is it checking, the no' of unique columns or some other thing